# Matlab: parfor loop and cell arrays not working

Tags: matlab, parfor

I get the following error: "The variable X_bs in a parfor cannot be
classified" when trying to run the following parfor loop:

```
  y = zeros(1000,1)
        parfor bb = 1:1000
            rng(bb)
            % deleted line: X_bs{8} = [];
            for ii = 1:8
                ind = ceil(N(ii)*rand(N(ii),1));
                X_bs{ii} = X{ii}(ind,:);
            end 

           y(bb) = another_function(X_bs)

        end
```

`X` is a 1x8 cell array, each cell containing a `N(ii)x4` matrix (`N(ii)` changes). The code re-samples rows of `X` and creates a cell array called `X_bs`.  I pass `X_bs` through a function that outputs the variable that I am interested in, `y(bb)`.

Why am I getting this error?  How do I get around this?

Here is an example:

```
 X{1} = [1 ; 2 ; 3]
 X{2} = [4 ; 5 ; 6; 7]
 N(1) = 3 % size of X{1}
 N(2) = 4 % size of X{2}
    parfor bb=1:10
        rng(bb)
        for ii = 1:2
            X_bs{ii} = zeros(N(ii),1);
            ind = ceil(N(ii)*rand(N(ii),1));
            X_bs{ii} = X{ii}(ind,:);
        end
        % Output is a function of X_bs.  For illustration, say it is the sum
        y(bb) = sum(X_bs{1}) + sum(X_bs{2});
    end
```

The above code gets the same error as earlier: "The variable X_bs in a parfor cannot be classified".  Here is a simpler version that does work and does not use cell structures:

```
X = [1 ; 2 ; 3]
N = 3; %size of X
parfor bb=1:10
    rng(bb)
    X_bs = zeros(N,1);
    ind = ceil(N*rand(N,1));
    X_bs= X(ind,:);
    y(bb) = sum(X_bs) 
end
```

The problem (I think) lies within overriding the cell structure.  Perhaps parfor treats cellstructures as a slicing variables rather than temporary variables.  Any thoughts?

Update: Adriaan suggested that there is a problem with the random vector `ind` and the cell structure `X_bs{ii}`.  Here is a simpler example that does not invoke the random vector ind and still has the same error:

```
X{1} = [1 ; 2 ; 3]
 X{2} = [4 ; 5 ; 6; 7]
 N(1) = 3 % size of X{1}
 N(2) = 4 % size of X{2}
    parfor bb=1:10
        for ii = 1:2
            X_bs{ii} = X{ii};
        end
        % Output is a function of X_bs.  For illustration, say it is the sum
        y(bb) = sum(X_bs{1}) + sum(X_bs{2});
    end
```

Therefore, I am fairly certain MatLab isn't treating the cell structure, `X_bs{ii}` , as a temporary variable.

Comment: I edited and changed shares_bs to X_bs to avoid confusion.  X_bs should be a temporary variable.  I still get the error after deleting the line  X_bs{8} = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution (thanks to Andriaan's comment) is to put the forloop that generates `X_bs` in a nested function, `randomize_X`.  See below for a solution to the working example:

```
X{1} = [1 ; 2 ; 3]
X{2} = [4 ; 5 ; 6; 7]
N(1) = 3 % size of X{1}
N(2) = 4 % size of X{2}
parfor bb=1:10
    [X_bs] = randomize_X(X,N)
    % Output is a function of X_bs.  For illustration, say it is the sum
    y(bb) = sum(X_bs{1}) + sum(X_bs{2});
end
```

where

```
function [X_bs] = randomize_X(X,N)
  for ii = 1:2
      X_bs{ii} = zeros(N(ii),1);
      ind = ceil(N(ii)*rand(N(ii),1));
      X_bs{ii} = X{ii}(ind,:);
  end
end
```

I'm fairly certain that the `parfor` loop treats cell structures as slicing variables, so it needs to be specified beforehand and cannot be overwritten within the `parfor` loop.  To get around this, a simple trick is send the computation of cell structures to another function.  The `parfoor` loop has similar problems with the optimization toolbox CVX.  The same trick can be employed - call CVX in a subroutine within `parfor`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is created on the line:

```
ind = ceil(N(ii)*rand(N(ii),1));
```

and surfaces here:

```
X_bs{ii} = X{ii}(ind,:);
```

The size of `ind` is "unknown" to MATLAB before executing the `parfor` and hence cannot run. `parfor` does not run in a consecutive order, making it paramount that all required sizes are specified beforehand. Probably you can circumvent this using `clear X_bs` just before the invocation of `y(bb)`, this removed them from memory and makes sure the contained matrices are not of different size than the ones you assigned the previous iteration.

If on the other hand this does not solve it, you can't parallelise this, since you are using random sized matrices each time. To expand on this: `rand(N(ii))` can produce quite a range of numbers. Regardless of that range, the important fact is that the range is *indeterminable*, meaning you cannot know what it will be before executing it. Even though this is normally no problem, since the cell will store any old matrix size, the `parfor` environment *requires* to know all sizes before hand, in order to optimise memory and CPU usage before assigning jobs to workers.

If possible: get the maximum value `ind` can attain and initialise the required matrix in a temporary variable to be the maximum allowable size and access only the used entries.

Comment: Having read up on `parfor` docs, here's a final guess: put *everything* inside the `parfor` in a function, that takes `bb` as an input argument. This way the `parfor` will most probably run, though I'm not sure whether it will speed up things.

Comment: Thanks.  I will see if that works.  It probably will as it is a similar trick that I used to call CVX or Knitro - MatLab had problems calling CVX within a parfor loop, but nesting a function inside of the loop worked perfectly fine.